# What is 500 error?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter as my Php framework. I have created simple room reservation system. In local I didn't get any error, but in server I got 500 error? What causes this type of error and how could I solve it?

Comment: make sure PHP is loaded

Comment: In localserver it is working fine, but in server it shows 500 error, the php is loaded fine

Comment: Read Remote server Error Logs.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
http://asrv-a.akamaihd.net/sd/1700/1043.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
http://salyani.com.np/booking/index.php/room_booking Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a server error indicating that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from filling the request. From [**the spec**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1):

> The 500 (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

It could be almost anything that causes an error in running your code, especially a parser or configuration error. Check your logs.

Comment: As I and others have said, you have to check your logs; we have no way to know what the problem is.

Comment: @self Have an upvote; your answer is also good. That said, your reason for downvoting isn't a very good one. I provided the first answer, and it was accurate, even if you got the spec link first. I would appreciate it if you would remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

10.5.1 **500** Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt